# Sorting the array of answers in a loop of poll options

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of poll options, and an array that is a set of poll results (votes).
With this code I cycle in all the options outputting a progress bar with the votes. What I need to to is to sort the options by results (most voted first), but I can't understand if and how it's possible to do it starting from here.

```
<? foreach ($poll["options"] as $optionKey => $option) {        
    $answer = $pollAnswerSet["answers"][$optionKey];
    $absolutePerc = $sum == 0 ? 0 : floor($answer/$sum * 100);
            
?>  
        <div>
            <div class='progress-bar' style="width:<?= $absolutePerc ?>%;"></div>
            <?= "$absolutePerc%" ?>
        </div>

        <?  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the data, it looks like you just sort the answers and then loop that.  You can use the answers key to access the option (if needed).
`arsort` will sort highest to lowest and maintain the keys:

```
arsort($pollAnswerSet["answers"]);

<?php foreach ($pollAnswerSet["answers"] as $key => $val) { 
    $option = $poll["options"][$key];      
    $absolutePerc = $sum == 0 ? 0 : floor($val/$sum * 100);
            
?>  
        <div>
            <div class='progress-bar' style="width:<?= $absolutePerc ?>%;"></div>
            <?= "$absolutePerc%" ?>
        </div>

<?php  } ?>
```

As short tags can be disabled it is recommended to only use the normal tags (`<?php ?>` and `<?= ?>`) to maximise compatibility.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you :)